# Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>’ to ‘System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel>’

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I got this problem when I'm trying join three tables `ProductPhoto`, `Product`, and `ProductProductPhoto`. I tried many case but it didn't work out. Anyone could help me get out of this? Thanks for replying!

```
private IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel> GetSubProduct()
            {
                var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
                var subcate = (from a in context.ProductPhotoes
                              join b in context.ProductProductPhotoes on a.ProductPhotoID equals b.ProductPhotoID
                              join c in context.Products on b.ProductID equals c.ProductID
                              join d in context.ProductSubcategories on c.ProductSubcategoryID equals d.ProductSubcategoryID
                              select new
                              {
                                  a.ProductPhotoID,
                                  a.ThumbnailPhotoFileName,
                                  c.ProductID,
                                  c.Name,
                                  d.NameofBike,
                                  d.isSelected,
                              }).AsQueryable();
                         return subcate;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code buddy..

```
private IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel> GetSubProduct()
                {
                    var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
                    var subcate = (from a in context.ProductPhotoes
                                  join b in context.ProductProductPhotoes on a.ProductPhotoID equals b.ProductPhotoID
                                  join c in context.Products on b.ProductID equals c.ProductID
                                  join d in context.ProductSubcategories on c.ProductSubcategoryID equals d.ProductSubcategoryID
                                  select new SubCateViewModel
                                  {
                                     ProductPhotoID =  a.ProductPhotoID,
                                      ThumbnailPhotoFileName = a.ThumbnailPhotoFileName,
                                     ProductID = c.ProductID,
                                      Name = c.Name,
                                      NameofBike = d.NameofBike,
                                      isSelected = d.isSelected,
                                  });
                             return subcate.AsEnumerable();
                }
```

Comment: I got the same error: `Cannot initialize type 'AdventureCycle.Models.SubCateViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: does it support subcate.AsEnumerable(); or (IEnumerable)subcate?

Comment: It supports `subcate.AsEnumerable();` but it red signal under `{ a.ProductPhotoID...` line and throw that error.

Comment: which { ur talking about?

Comment: `{ a.ProductPhotoID, a.ThumbnailPhotoFileName,...` @Neel

Comment: what are the properties in ur SubCateViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a list of your anonymous type can't be converted to a list of SubCateViewModel .

Why are you using an anonymous type, anyway? Simply create a new SubCateViewModel instance in your query (Select a SubCateViewModel instead of an anonymous type).

Instead of Anonymous type in LINQ use:

```
select new SubCateViewModel 
{
// Set class variables here...
}
```

Comment: I fixed follow your answer but it throw new error: `Cannot initialize type 'AdventureCycle.Models.SubCateViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: is `SubCateViewModel ` your database table or user generated model

Comment: It's user generated model @Nilesh